# ERROR 000732: Cannot clip IDW product to boundary file with Python script

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000732, idle

I am writing a Python script to try to clip a raster generated by Idw_3d interpolation, but it's throwing the infamous 000732 error. I've looked at my file path, and it does exist there. I've opened it up with ArcMap, and it's there. However, I still get the error saying:
 `ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset precipNew does not exist or is not supported`

Note: I'm using IDLE for my IDE.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#Not the actual workspace, it has been changed for this example
env.workspace = "C:\\Documents\\WeatherData.shp"
env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3d")

#arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() indicates that all of the data is present that I need to work with.

#Declare local variables
precipPoints = "PrecipMontana2014"

#Make feature class for the points to be interpolated
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "points_lyr")

#IDW
arcpy.Idw_3d(in_point_features ="points_lyr", z_field = "RASTERVALU", out_raster = "precipNew")

####Everything works fine until this point, when I try to clip it####

#MontanaBoundary is the boundary I want to clip the IDW raster to

arcpy.Clip_analysis(in-features = "precipNew", clip_features = "MontanaBoundary", out_feature_class = "output1")
```

The error then throws after this line.

Comment: I should have proofread it better, it should be ```arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(precipPoints, "points_lyr")```, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arcpy.Clip_management()` to clip a raster, not `arcpy.Clip_analysis()` which is for clipping a vector feature class.

See:  [Clip (vector) documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm)

and:  [Clip (raster) documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm)

Comment: I tried that, both in the IDLE shell and creating a script, but I always get the ```RESTART: Shell``` notification. Would you happen to know why that would happen? It always wants to restart (without completing the process) when I run the ```arcpy.Clip_management``` process.

Comment: You may need to post your full code (perhaps as a separate new question).